# Hi guys, looking to insert some HTML through JS, how can put the output inside separate divs so i can style better?

Tags: javascript, html

looking to insert some HTML through JS, how can put the output inside separate divs so i can style better?

Code here:

```
--- HTML ---

<!--  TEAMSHEET -->

      <div id="teamsheet" class="teams-sheet mb-4">
        <h4 class="pt-3 pb-2">Teams Sheet</h4>
      </div>


---JS-- 

const getTeams = () => {
  const teamSize = Math.ceil(playersArr.length / 2);

  const teamOne = playersArr.slice(0, teamSize);
  const teamTwo = playersArr.slice(teamSize);

  teams.push(teamOne, teamTwo);
  

  //  TEAMSHEET //
  
  let ol = document.createElement('ol')
  ol.classList.add('team-container')
  for (let i of teamOne) { 
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.classList.add('team-sheet-player')
    li.innerHTML = i
    ol.appendChild(li)
    teamSheet.appendChild(ol);
}

let olB = document.createElement('ol')
olB.classList.add('team-container')
for (let i of teamTwo) { 
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.classList.add('team-sheet-player')
  li.innerHTML = i
  olB.appendChild(li)
  teamSheet.appendChild(olB);
}
}


genBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  getTeams()
})
```

Ideally what i'm looking for is add inside "#teamsheet" 2 more divs, one for each team, each div to have an icon also.

Thnak you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a lot of corrections and assumption about what you need. Please take a look. Hope it helps.

Happy coding!

```js
const getTeams = () => {
  playersArr = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
  const teamSize = Math.ceil(playersArr.length / 2);

  const teamOne = playersArr.slice(0, teamSize);
  const teamTwo = playersArr.slice(teamSize);

  const teams = new Array(); 
  teams.push(teamOne, teamTwo);

  //  TEAMSHEET //
  const teamSheet = document.getElementById('teamsheet');
  
  //  TEAM 1
  let div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.setAttribute("id", "teamOne");
    let ol = document.createElement('ol')
    ol.classList.add('team-container')
    for (let i of teamOne) { 
      let li = document.createElement('li')
      li.classList.add('team-sheet-player')
      li.innerHTML = i
      ol.appendChild(li)
      div1.appendChild(ol);
    }   
  teamSheet.appendChild(div1);


  //  TEAM 2
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.setAttribute("id", "teamTwo");
    let olB = document.createElement('ol')
    olB.classList.add('team-container')
    for (let i of teamTwo) { 
      let li = document.createElement('li')
      li.classList.add('team-sheet-player')
      li.innerHTML = i
      olB.appendChild(li)
      div2.appendChild(olB);
    }
  teamSheet.appendChild(div2);
}


document.getElementById('genBtn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  getTeams()
})
```

```html
<div id="teamsheet" class="teams-sheet mb-4">
        <h4 class="pt-3 pb-2">Teams Sheet</h4>
      </div>

<button id='genBtn'>get</div>
```

Comment: Hi Marat thank you for your reply. What is was looking for exactly is to put each OL in it's on div.

```
div(#teamsheet) > div(#teamOne) > ol > li
-----
 div(#teamsheet) > div(#teamTwo)> olB > li
```

Comment: Hello Andrei. Please take a look. I edited the code above to. As far as I understand you wanted to create each team in separate divs. Hope it is what you need if so please Accept my answer as correct one. Have a great day.